# "You are close to new privilege" - Where? (In which site?)

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app, privileges

In the activity feed of the Android app, there's this new milestone tracking and reminders with a "bolt" like icon, which says:

> You're close to a new privilege!
>
> < privilege details > at < rep count >

While all this is OK, but how do I know in which SE am I close to that privilege?

It does not redirect me anywhere, nor it has a favicon of the particular site on it's left.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE App v1.0.78 (beta). If possible, add a screenshot, since I think I understand the issue, but not sure without any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not reproduced on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE App v1.0.78 (beta).

> [image: privilege with favicon]

<sup>"Close to a new privilege" feed entry with favicon</sup>

However, on your case, it seems that the entry about "close to a new privilege" is an extension of the site's other entries. In this case, only the first line has the favicon, but subsequent lines won't have (I guess to prevent repetition).

> [image]

<sup>"Earned a new badge" feed entry not having favicon, but following the previous entry's site (Stack Overflow)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, seems like I haven't noticed it as an extension.   But, it is confusing (at least for me) when you are in multiple sites where you're close to that privilege.